# accessing korbit api with python http.client

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitcoin, http.client

i've been trying to access following api:
https://api.korbit.co.kr/v1/ticker/detailed

i know i can access this using any internet browser, 
but i am having hard time implementing it to python.

I used following code:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("https://api.korbit.co.kr", 443)
conn.request("GET", "/v1/ticker/detailed")
response = conn.getresponse()
data = response.read()
conn.close()
```

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/K/PycharmProjects/nektie/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    conn.request("GET", "/v1/ticker/detailed")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1090, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1128, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1086, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 924, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 859, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1221, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 836, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 491, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 530, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`http.client.HTTPSConnection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPSConnection) accepts hostname, not a url.

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.korbit.co.kr", 443)
```

BTW, I recommend to use library like [`python-requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.korbit.co.kr/v1/ticker/detailed')
data = r.json()
```

Comment: python-requests solved my other problems too, i love you